# Why I lose formatting on Post or Edit content using TinyMCE cloud?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have installed TinyMCE cloud on my WordPress front-end comments. Now, I use it on WordPress and when I submit new post or edit existing post I lose formats I added before submit.

Please check the images:

**Screenshot 1:**

Writing content, each block of text added between `<p></p>`.

[image]

**Screenshot 2:**

When submit the form the content and all text combined inside one `<p></p>` and the normal `<p>` replaced with `<br>`

[image]

**Screenshot 3:**

When editing the post the content also combined as 1 paragraph and ignoring all formats I added.

[image]

Can you please let me know how to resolve that?

Thank you

Comment: Its may be that the comments are filtered by WordPress using `wp_kses` and/or `esc_html` or one of their related functions. These are in place to prevent malicious actors from adding html to you pages

Comment: Thanks @JasperB I doubted in that, but when disabled the functions you mentioned still wrapping the text as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is, if you're copying in content, is to switch on the  [TinyMCE power paste plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/powerpaste/). This can help control what HTML is going into your textarea.

It looks like this could be an issue with the power paste plugin if you already have it running. the Power Paste plugin might be applying merge formats. The option  merges identical text format elements. The goal is to reduce the number of HTML elements in text. The plugin may be merging the paragraphs together when the document is published.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea', 
  plugins: 'powerpaste',
  menubar: 'edit',
  toolbar: 'pastetext',
  paste_as_text: false, //change this to false if you have power paste enabled to stop merging tags
});
```

Something to help diagnose what's going on here is to turn on the [Tiny Code plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/code/). This is one of the
Open Source plugins. You can add it to your toolbar to open a dialog and see exactly what is happening
with the HTML:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: 'code',
  toolbar: 'code',
  menubar: 'tools'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it our, the issue was due to these functions:

```
/* Kses stip */
if (!function_exists('wpqa_kses_stip')) :
    function wpqa_kses_stip($value,$ireplace = "",$p_active = "") {
        return wpqa_deslash(wp_kses(($ireplace == "yes"?str_ireplace(array("<br />","<br>","<br/>","</p>"), "\r\n",$value):$value),wpqa_html_tags(($p_active == "yes"?$p_active:""))));
    }
endif;

/* Kses stip wpautop */
if (!function_exists('wpqa_kses_stip_wpautop')) :
    function wpqa_kses_stip_wpautop($value,$ireplace = "",$p_active = "") {
        return wpqa_deslash(wpautop(wp_kses((($ireplace == "yes"?str_ireplace(array("<br />","<br>","<br/>","</p>"), "\r\n",$value):$value)),wpqa_html_tags(($p_active == "yes"?$p_active:"")))));
    }
endif;
```

When disabled, the TinyMCE worked as normal.